# iOS: Repeat animation block until an event completes

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have the following animation block, which spins a button once.  I would like to continue the button spinning until the `refreshPendingRequests` method has finished.

The `refreshPendingRequests` method retrieves data from my server, so I would like continue spinning the button until I have retrieved the data.

```
CGFloat direction = 1.0f;  // -1.0f to rotate other way
refreshButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0
                             options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModePaced | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                          animations:^{
                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.0 animations:^{
                                  refreshButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 2.0f / 3.0f * direction);
                              }];
                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.0 animations:^{
                                  refreshButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 4.0f / 3.0f * direction);
                              }];
                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.0 animations:^{
                                  refreshButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                              }];
                          }
                          completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                              [self performSelector:@selector(refreshPendingRequests) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
                          }];
```

Does anyone know if there is some type of `repeats` property that I could call or how I can perform this animation until the `refreshPendingRequests` event is finished?

Comment: Why'd you place a call to refreshPendingRequests in the completion block? That means that every second (since your animation duration is 1.0) you'll be calling `refreshPendingRequests` again. I suspect this isn't what you want.

Comment: @SantaClaus Ah definitely not what I want, I just want the spinning to continue until `refreshPendingRequests` has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for this indeed: `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat`.

Pass that option in, and pass nil for your completion block, since you shouldn't need it.

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0
                             options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModePaced | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat
                          animations:^{
                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.0 animations:^{
                                  refreshButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 2.0f / 3.0f * direction);
                              }];
                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.0 animations:^{
                                  refreshButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 4.0f / 3.0f * direction);
                              }];
                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.0 animations:^{
                                  refreshButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                              }];
                          }
                          completion:nil];
```

Then when your refresh completes:

```
[refreshButton.layer removeAllAnimations];
```